# Nodejs crypto setEngine

Tags: node.js, openssl, node-crypto

I'm trying to load gost openssl engine with crypto.setEngine function. The only working way was to specify a full path to dylib (e.g. "/opt/local/lib/engines/libgost.dylib'").
But I still can not use digest from loaded engine. Call to crypto.createSign('md_gost94') fails with "Unknown message digest" error.

AFAIK node.js goes with bundled openssl. Does it include engines like gost? Should it work with external dylib for engine?

I use MacOSX 10.10 with nodejs v0.12.2.

Thank you!

**UPDATE** It works fine on Ubuntu 12.04 system with system libgost.so module. On OSX I had to use openssl installed with ports because system openssl is obsolete.